# Hot CPU in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: cpu, fan, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04

I have problem in ubuntu 18.04 which was not occurred in ubuntu 16.04. My CPU got so hot nearly 70 degree Celsius and fan is running at maximum speed while there is no process running. I wonder if the problem is with graphic card or anything else?

My laptop specification : DELL- N5110 -core i5 -Nvidia 525m

Comment: Have you installed drivers for the Nvidia card? Are you running Xorg or Wayland?

Comment: I have installed NVIDIA V.390
I don't know how I can check if I use Xorg or Wayland

Comment: The default for 18.04 is Xorg but you can try Wayland by clicking the cog wheel that allows selecting different sessions at the login screen (gdm). Wayland should work better.

Comment: Do you have n5110 with Ubuntu 18.04 installed?

Comment: No, I don't but that's irrelevant.

Comment: You say “no process running” but is that actually the case? Check with `top`, `htop` or some GUI tool. Is the CPU perhaps busy?

Comment: it does happen on the fresh installation of ubuntu 18.04. Although for now I put my foot backward and went back to xenial.

Comment: 16.04 (Xenial) is probably better for your hardware. I've read about and personally experienced several issues with 18.04 in some PCs. The differences are huge, unlike what happened before between 14.04 and 16.04. Xorg seems "broken" and was made the default anyway; Wayland seems to work better but some apps don't run correctly or at all. Exception is the new VLC that runs in Wayland (horrible interface) and doesn't in Xorg.